# Why Date is showing as 21\/1\/2015 after json parsing instead of 21/1/2015, Android?

Tags: android, json, datepicker, tostring

I am using DatePicker in my code. And sending the value through json. The value I want as 21/1/2015 removing the extra \'s. How to solve this?

```
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
        myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
        updateLabel();
    }

    private void updateLabel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            String myFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //In which you need put here
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

            edit_message3.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

            }

edit_message3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(SignupActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

String birthday = edit_message3.getText().toString();
```

Comment: `is 21/1/2015 instead of 21/1/2015` is same right?

Comment: Please see my question above. It is auto-correcting the \'s.

Comment: Use code markup to prevent interpreting the backslashes. Also post the code you've having trouble with.

Comment: Is `21\/1\/2015` occurring in your json string?

Comment: Yes, EdmDroid. How to solve that?

Comment: I have posted my code, laalto ! Please check.

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem by replacing "\/" with "-".

Answer (score 0):

```
birthday = birthday.replaceAll("\/","/");
```

and then send the value of birthday or you can try this..

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int pDay=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
    int pMonth=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int pYear=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);



@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    @Deprecated
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        //return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month, day);

        return new DatePickerDialog(this, pDateSetListener, pYear, pMonth, pDay);

    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                              int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int currentday=c.get(Calendar.DATE);
            int currentmonth=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            currentmonth = currentmonth+1;
            int currentyear=c.get(Calendar.YEAR);


                 birthday = selectedDay + "/" + (selectedMonth + 1) + "/"
                        + selectedYear;
Log.i("DOB >>", birthday);

        }
    };



@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(0);
            }
```

Comment: It is showing: Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \\ )

Comment: Just a suggestion: you should try and provide a more complete answer, explain why he should do that.

Comment: I have also tried as birthday = birthday.replaceAll("\\/","/"); But the output is same. :(

Comment: Hey,  pjco. It is because I am getting the json string output  as birthday: 10\/02\/2015

Comment: Hey, I solved the problem by replacing "\/" with "-"